# Display Two Classes Java

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics, jframe

so I am new to designing graphics in Java  I was wondering if anyone could help me here. I have two classes and I want to display both of them at the same time in a JFrame. But only one or the other get displayed.

```
 public class Tutorial extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
  Background bc = new Background();
 Timer tm = new Timer(5,this);
  int x =0, velX = 2;
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(x, 30, 50, 30);
    tm.start();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(x<0 || x>550){
        velX = -velX;
    }
    x = x+ velX;
    repaint();

}


  public static  void main(String [] args){
    Background bc = new Background();
    Tutorial t = new Tutorial();
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    jf.setTitle("Tutorial");
    jf.setSize(600,400);
    jf.setVisible(true);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.add(t);
    jf.add(bc);



}
```

My second class

```
 public class Background extends Canvas {

    public void paint(Graphics g){
      g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
      g.fillRect(0,0,600,125);
      g.fillRect(0,250,600,125);
      g.setColor(Color.black);
      g.fillRect(0,125,600,125);

  }
```

For some reason I can only get either Background to be displayed or Tutorial?
Can anyone point me in the right direction or tell me where I am going wrong. I want to be able to display multiple things like these classes in the one window

Answer (score 2):

The default **layout manager** of a JFrame is a **BorderLayout**.

By using the single-argument JFrame.add() function, you're adding both of the components to the BorderLayout.CENTER portion of your JFrame. This means that you'll only see one of the components.

The solution is to either use a different layout manager, or to add the components to different sections of your BorderLayout.

More info here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html